# Como ordenar os dados de uma consulta por valores pré-definidos?

Tags: mysql, classificação

Usando como exemplo, tenho uma determinada tabela de usuários, onde a cidade desse usuário está, é uma referência a outra tabela.

Preciso que a ordem desses usuários numa consulta se dê de acordo com a localidade do usuário atual logado. 
Exemplo, se eu moro em `Belo Horizonte`, primeiro devem ser exibidos nessa consulta os dados do usuário de `Belo Horizonte`.

Sei que no MySQL o `ORDER BY` funciona como meio de ordenação pelo valor presente na coluna, mas não sei como posso fazer uma ordenação por valores específicos.

Por exemplo, quero que a ordem seja: `Belo  Horizonte` e daí pra frente não faz diferença.

Em um exemplo fictício mostrarei o que quero:

Primeiro pego o valor da cidade:

```
$valor = Auth::user()->cidade->nome; // 'Belo Horizonte'
```

Depois quero que a ordenação dos registros comece pelos usuários que tenham a mesma cidade e, depois disso, seja indiferente.

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN cidade.id = usuarios.cidade_id
ORDER BY <cidade.nome COMEÇANDO DE $valor>
```

<sup>Código fictício - eu sei que daria erro de síntaxe, é só a demonstração do que quero.</sup>

Existe alguma maneira de ordenar os dados de uma consulta, sem ser pelo campo da tabela, mas por valores especificados pré-definidos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios 
INNER JOIN estados e on e.id = usuarios.estado_id
ORDER BY e.sigla = 'MG' DESC, e.sigla
```

[A referência está aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Answer (score 6):

Sim, podes fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM usuarios 
INNER JOIN estados
   ON estados.id = usuarios.estado_id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN estados.nome = $valor THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, estados.nome
```

A lógica é bastante simples, caso o estado do utilizador seja o indicado na variável $valor, então atribuimos o valor 1 (indicando maior prioridade), caso contrário atribuímos 2. Após isso podes utilizar qualquer outra coluna para ordenar os restantes registos. Neste caso ordeno por ordem alfabética de estados.

Aqui tens o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e9f3) para ver o funcionamento na prática.

Answer (score 5):

Sim, você pode especificar literalmente os valores que queres que apareçam primeiro na consulta:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM usuarios 
INNER JOIN estados
  ON estados.id = usuarios.estado_id
ORDER BY estados.sigla = 'MG', estados.sigla asc
```

Answer (score 4):

Ficaria desse modo, caso tenha o Acre e Alagoas, irá ordenar pelos mesmos, se não tiver nenhum dos dois irá ordenar por Amazonas :

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN estados.id = usuarios.estado_id
ORDER BY CASE estados.nome
  WHEN 'Acre' THEN 'Acre'
  WHEN 'Alagoas' THEN 'Alagoas'
  ELSE 'Amazonas'
END ASC
```