# Existe alguma maneira de definir um order by randômico para uma ordem já estabelecida?

Tags: mysql, classificação, random

Se o título da minha pergunta ficou confusa, eu explico: Quero ordenar um resultado de uma determinada consulta do `MYSQL`.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM 
     usuarios
ORDER BY 
    cidade = 'BH' DESC,
    cargo = 'Programador' DESC
```

Porém gostaria que, se mais de um usuário caísse no mesmo quesito da ordenação (por exemplo, o usuário tem a mesma cidade e o mesmo cargo nessa ordenação), a ordenação fosse randômica.

Exemplo:

```
|   nome    |   cargo       |   cidade  |
-----------------------------------------
| wallace   |   programador |   bh      |

| helbert   |   programador |   bh      |

| simão   |   programador |   sp        |

| miguel    |   venda       |   sp      |
```

No exemplo acima, *wallace* e *helbert* casam com a ordenação do `cargo` e `cidade` simultaneamente.
Porém, idependente do critério que o `MYSQL` vai usar depois dessa ordenação, queria que entre esses dois (quando são idênticos) o resultado fosse randômico.

Ou seja, caso os resultados do `ORDER BY` resultem na mesma quantidade de itens que casem com a ordenação, quero que a próxima ordenação entre eles sejam randômica (uma hora *wallace* será primeiro, outra hora poderá ser *helbert*).

Com faço isso no `MYSQL`?

Comment: Qnd vc trás do banco o fetch array na variavek nao fica assim $consulta[0]['nome']. Vc poderia fazer usar o hand com o limite de consultas exemplo tem 10 consultas vc faz um  $aleatorio= hand(0,9). E quando fosse usar o array colocaria no array $consulta[$aleatorio]['nome'].  E caso vc n saiba o limite de cada consulta tem uma função que diz o tamanho do array ou usa o count nao me recordo bem.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel não entendi nada. Eu uso o `Laravel` para isso, não uso o `PDO` puro ou o `mysqli_`.  Mas a pergunta não tem relação com o PHP e sim com `MYSQL`.

Comment: Sua consulta no banco retorna uma array correto?

Comment: Sim. Você não está me sugerindo usar um `shuffle` no `array`, né? Porque isso invalidaria minha ordenação vinda do banco. Como disse, quero a solução SOMENTE em `MYSQL`.

Comment: vc nao que que quando cargo e cidade for igual faca um hand no nome correto?

Comment: Acredito ser mais fácil trazer a consulta e depois fazer um hand com a consulta na condição de cargo e cidade forem iguais.

Comment: Wallace, desconheço a possibilidade desta inteligência no MySQL. É preciso analisar todos os pontos. Por que você precisa disso? Como quer a saída de dados? por que a saída de dados não podem ser conforme é o output do mysql? Eu não vejo utilidade para os dados saírem assim. Lembre-se também a da responsabilidade de dados, as vezes nem tudo é a cargo do DBA e sim do dev.

Comment: Dá pra fazer sim, acabei descobrindo. Só estou analisando agora qual das maneiras será a melhor pra postar aqui

Answer (score 4):

Acabei descobrindo que é algum bem simples. Segue o mesmo raciocínio da pergunta [Como ordenar os dados de uma consulta por valores pré-definidos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86891/como-ordenar-os-dados-de-uma-consulta-por-valores-pr%C3%A9-definidos?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Uma questão importante é que o `ORDER BY`, quando utilizado com mais de uma condição de ordenação, funciona da mesma forma que uma ordenação por letras do alfabeto, quando coincidem que duas letras começem com `A`: Ela parte para a ordenação a partir da próxima letra.

Exemplo:

```
 ABC
 AZX
 ADC
```

A ordenação por letras seria

```
ABC
ADC
AZX
```

Isso por conta do segundo critério (que é a segunda letra da palavra).

A mesma coisa acontece com o `ORDER BY.

Já que eu quero que valores de mesma ordenação sejam randômicos, basta adicionar a função `RAND` como terceiro fator de ordenação.

Isso vai ficar assim:

```
SELECT * FROM 
     usuarios
ORDER BY 
    cidade = 'BH' DESC,
    cargo = 'Programador' DESC,
    RAND()
```

Comment: Cuidado com o custo de performance ao utilizar essas conditions.

Comment: Bem que você avisou. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87450/por-que-order-by-rand-deixa-a-consulta-lenta-existe-outra-alternativa