# Por que ORDER BY RAND() deixa a consulta lenta? Existe outra alternativa?

Tags: mysql, random

Eu tinha acabado de fazer perguntas a respeito de ordenação de valores randômicos através do `MYSQL`.

Daí comecei a notar uma incômoda lentidão no sistema sugestão de amizades aqui da empresa.

Eu uso o `Laravel 3`. Fui fazer uma checagem do que poder estar deixando o sistema lento.

Daí obtive os seguintes resultados numa consulta. Nos dois casos, estou usando  `LIMIT 10`.

Com o `RAND()`:

```
 85.203170776367
 6.6289901733398
```

Sem `RAND()`

```
0.074863433837891
0.11181831359863
```

Com é que o `MYSQL` utiliza o `ORDER BY RAND()` internamente - pra ficar tão lento?

Quais possíveis alterativas para obter os resultados no `MYSQL`randomicamente.

## Atualização

Fiz mais testes utilizando o `MYSQL` diretamente com o PhpMyAdmin.

Vejam.

Com `RAND()`:

```
 SELECT * FROM pessoa ORDER BY RAND()
 #A mostrar registos de 0 - 29 (9024 total, O Query demorou 1.0453 sec)
```

Sem `RAND()`:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoa ORDER BY id
#A mostrar registos de 0 - 29 (9024 total, O Query demorou 0.0008 sec)
```

Comment: os valores numéricos estão em milisegundos, certo?

Comment: No código fonte do laravel está assim: `(microtime(true) - $start) * 1000`

Comment: Idependente da medida, dá pra ver a diferença de performance. kkkkk

Comment: sério que demora 85 segundos ?  quantos registros possui a tabela? 40 bilhões de registros ? rsrsrs  Mesmo usando rand(), não deveria passar de 0.4 numa consulta pequena a uma tabela com 100 mil registros e sem nenhuma otimização.. tudo no default.

Comment: vc quer um resultado aleatorio(que pode ser repetido) ou vc quer sempre um resultado diferente do anterior?

Comment: a sua tabela tem 9024 registros, certo ? Com certeza tem algum problema na tabela.. Pode estar usando indices em demasia ou de forma errada..   Uma consulta com `ORDER BY RAND() limit 10;` normalmente retornaria em 0.04 segundos num server com setagens default, sem otimizações..

Comment: Vou te mostrar a consulta que estou fazendo. Vai ficar de cabelo em pé

Comment: manda essa bagaça pra nós ver!

Comment: Chora nesse [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/BS841T1R)

Comment: Quando tira o `RAND` é que dá um grau

Comment: imaginei que fosse um monstrinho .. rsrs  tem muito subselect, mas nao quer dizer que seja o problema.. pode ser mal uso ou falta uso de indices ou chaves tal como relacionamentos (chave estrangeira).. poste o DDL das tabelas envolvidas.

Comment: e aí, galera? alguma novidade?

Comment: Sim. Ronaldinho Gaúcho saiu do Fluminense, do nada...

Answer (score 5):

Ele demora porque ele funciona de uma maneira que precise gerar um número randômico para cada linha da tabela. Depois ele ordena essas linhas e retorna uma delas, de acordo com esses números randômicos.

Então, quanto mais linhas tiver sua tabela, mais vai demorar.

Uma alternativa seria reduzir o número de linhas a gerar esse número randômico.
Podes fazer isso limitando o número de linhas que você necessite, por exemplo 1 número seria `LIMIT 1`, e dividir pelo total de números da tabela,`COUNT(*)` e então multiplicar por 10 para evitar retornar menos linhas do que você precise.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((1/COUNT(*))*10) FROM tabela) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

**Vantagem**: Fácil de usar em consultas complicadas e fácil de ajustar o número de linhas necessárias: bastar modificar o `LIMIT numeroDesejado`.

**Desvantagem**: o tempo de resposta ainda depende do número de linhas que você quer que retorne.

Não cheguei a testar, mas de acordo com o artigo de referência para essa resposta melhorou muito.

Referência: http://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/

Neste artigo ele apresenta outras alternativas com suas vantagens e desvantagens. Mas a escolhida como melhor alternativa foi esta exposta aqui pela sua melhor eficiência e facilidade de uso.