# SELECT com dois resultados

Tags: sql, query, select

Tabela: PESSOAS

```
id - nome
1 - BEATRIZ
2 - MARIA
3 - CARLOS
4 - MARIA
5 - JÉSSICA
6 - HENRIQUE
```

Como faço um `SELECT` que me dê como resultado uma lista com os nomes ordenados pelo `ID descendente`, porém, um determinado NOME primeiro e abaixo a continuação?

Tipo: primeiro as MARIAS e abaixo a continuação por ordem alfabética e ID DESC.

```
SELECT * FROM PESSOAS WHERE nome='MARIA' OR nome!='MARIA' ORDER BY nome, id DESC
```

Dessa forma não da erro, porém a `query` me retorna a lista normalmente ordenado apenas pela `id DESC` e não com o nome MARIA no topo da listagem.

Comment: `nome='MARIA' OR nome!='MARIA'` isso está bem errado, nem precisava desse WHERE, ele é a mesma coisa que nada. Mas irei responder sua pergunta

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ordenar os dados de uma consulta por valores pré-definidos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86891/como-ordenar-os-dados-de-uma-consulta-por-valores-pr%c3%a9-definidos)

Comment: "MARIA" tem que ser o primeiro nome ou é para listar primeiro todas as linhas que o termo "MARIA" faça parte do nome? // A coluna nome possui somente um termo?

Comment: @CíceroAntônio qual o banco que você usa?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode tentar forçar um `case`na cláusula `ORDER BY`, eu já fiz e ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PESSOA  
 WHERE NOME = 'MARIA' OR NOME != 'MARIA' 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN ((NOME  = 'MARIA') OR (NOME != 'MARIA')) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, NOME, ID;
```

**Editado**

Caso queira que apenas um registro fique no topo (o que não vai acontecer no SQL acima), recomendo que utilize apenas uma condição no `ORDER BY`. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PESSOA  
 WHERE NOME = 'MARIA' OR NOME != 'MARIA' 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN (NOME  = 'MARIA') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, NOME, ID;
```

**Editado**

Para deixar o seu `SQL` com um resultado melhor, visto que a forma atual não é uma boa prática, segue sugestão:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PESSOA  
 WHERE NOME LIKE '%MARIA%' 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN (NOME LIKE '%MARIA%') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, NOME, ID;
```

Deste forma, iremos retornar todos os nome que possuem Maria, de `Ana Maria` até `Maria Braga`, mas desta forma o primeiro registro do retorno irá obedecer à segunda cláusula, que é `NOME`, por exemplo:

1: Ana Maria

2: Anna Maria

3: Maria Braga

E assim por diante.

Comment: Interessante sua solução, só um detalhe: todas as linhas irão ficar com `0`, a segunda verificação no `WHEN` não pode existir.

Comment: Tens razão, mas caso ele queria que apenas um cliente fica no topo, deve existir apenas uma condição de igualdade, removendo o `NOME != 'MARIA'`. Concorda?

Comment: Só fiz por base no exemplo dele, vou editar a resposta :D

Comment: Sua cláusula `where` é praticamente tautológica. Tem o mesmo efeito de `where NOME is not NULL`

Comment: Como eu disse, eu respondi por base no SQL dele. Não estou aqui para questionar a lógica que ele utilizou, não sei o resultado final que ele espera usando desta forma, estou apenas tentando ajudá-lo. :D
Mas de qualquer forma, não faz sentido.

Comment: Mas aí você está perpetuando algo ruim. Melhor seria explicar o porquê de isso ser sem nexo, não concorda? No lugar de perpetuar uma coisa ruim?

Comment: O que eu quero é que o sistema me retorne uma lista colocando um resultado no topo e abaixo a continuação. Eu poderia fazer isso criando duas query: uma pra MARIA e outra pra os nomes diferente de MARIA. Mias seria duas pesquisas e o que quero é melhoras no desempenho.Estou analisando cada resposta. Esse CASE WHEN é algo novo pra mim estou analisando. Eu uso PHP.

Comment: @CíceroAntônio isso é sql puro, não interfere na sua vida no php.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, fiz uma edição. Veja o que acha agora. Se houver algum ponto, por favor, ajuste.

Comment: Você não explicou porquê de ser uma má prática. Também não explicou a tautologia de `a == b OR a != b` segunda a lógica proposicional, axioma do terceiro excluído. Agora está pegando ignorando as não Marias, que não é o desejado, mas sim priorizar as Marias

Comment: Essa é minha query real: SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE bairro_id = 5 OR bairro_id != 5 ORDER BY CASE WHEN ((bairro_id = 5) OR (bairro_)id != 5)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id DESC ela deve me retornar da tabela NOTICIAS primeiro as noticias do bairro cuja ID = 5 e depois continuar com os outros bairros. Fiz conforme seu exemplo mais o resultado ainda estar sendo o mesmo. Ele mostra a lista, mas, no final ordena unicamente pela ID DESC

Comment: Cícero, remova o `OR` da cláusula `ORDER BY` que faz referência ao `(BAIRRO_ID != 5)`.

Comment: Valeu @LucasdeSouzaCruz resolveu aqui. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Marca a resposta como útil pra ajudar a comunidade :D

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro ele vai pegar todas as 'maria'+sobrenome, depois ele retorna o restante ordenado alfabeticamente.

```
SELECT * from pessoas ORDER BY nome LIKE 'maria%' desc, nome
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908079/4438007

Comment: A sua base é a resposta do Chris: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908079/4438007 ; posso sugerir colocar o link para ela, no lugar do link da pergunta?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado com certeza ! não sabia que tinha esse recurso :P

Comment: Corrige a resposta. Ao invés de `nome='maria'` o correto é `nome LIKE 'maria%'`. Segundo ele: `Tipo: primeiro as MARIAS e abaixo a continuação por ordem alfabética e ID DESC.`

Comment: Marias = plural de MARIA...

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti botão compartilhar da resposta, você obtém o link adequado

Comment: Ahhh, entendi... desculpa, my bad, tipo 'maria silva', meu codigo se prenderia a apenas 'maria'

Comment: @ValdeirPsr pronto, obrigado, estava totalmente errado kkk

Answer (score -1):

Caso queria exibir especificamente a lista de um determinado nome e depois o resto dos dados, como no exemplo que você citou.

Você pode fazer isso através da união( [UNION](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql) ) de duas consultas.

Mas para que a ordenação funcione você terá de criar uma coluna para definir a prioridade de ordenação, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT Id, Nome, 0 Ordem
FROM Pessoas 
WHERE nome LIKE 'Maria%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Nome, 1 Ordem 
FROM Pessoas 
WHERE nome NOT LIKE 'Maria%'
ORDER BY Ordem, Nome
```

Segue exemplo online:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f96a7b/9)

Respondendo a seu comentário. Faltou criar a coluna Ordem na query:

```
SELECT *, 0 Ordem FROM noticias WHERE bairro_id=5 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, 1 Ordem FROM noticias WHERE bairro_id <> 5 
ORDER BY Ordem, id DESC
```

Comment: Não foi isso que el epediu

Comment: Já existe uma resposta com `UNION`

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti foi pedido para ordenar "Marias", não foi?

Comment: @RobertodeCampos a resposta do Caique coloca a coluna `ordem` que permite de fato selecionar primeiro as Marias e depois as outras pessoas. A outra resposta com `UNION` está errada

Comment: Não estou disputando a resposta correta, mas a sua primeira resposta é incorreta !

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti , não foi ele quem editou e a resposta responde à pergunta, como deixar Marias no topo.

Comment: Essa é minha query real utilizando seu exemplo: SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE bairro_id=5 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE bairro_id<>5 ORDER BY id DESC ela deve me retornar da tabela NOTICIAS primeiro as noticias do bairro cuja ID = 5 e depois continuar com os outros bairros. Fiz conforme seu exemplo mais o resultado ainda estar sendo o mesmo. Ele mostra a lista, mas, no final ordena unicamente pela ID DESC

Comment: @CíceroAntônio Faltou a coluna "a mais" note na minha resposta que eu crio uma coluna no select e a nomeio como Ordem, editei minha resposta incluindo sua query para te auxiliar.

Answer (score -1):

Valeu pessoal:

Meu problema foi resolvido com a query

```
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE bairro_id = 5 OR bairro_id != 5 ORDER BY CASE WHEN (bairro_id = 5) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id DESC
```

O exemplo com a tabela acima foi só pra enfatizar. A ideia é que o sistema me retorna uma lista ordenada por bairros, primeiro colocando um determinado bairro no topo e continuar a lista com os demais bairros.

Fica ai o post pra outros usuários com a mesma dificuldade.

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Agora que vi esta sua resposta. (1) Acho que o filtro `WHERE bairro_id = 5 OR bairro_id != 5` é completamente inútil; (2) No texto você cita `primeiro as MARIAS e abaixo a continuação por ordem alfabética e ID DESC`; são 3 crítérios para ordenação! O código que postou como solução não atende a esse requisito.

Comment: Faltou as marias ...

Comment: Além das marias, isso mesmo @MarconcilioSouza!   rs